# Laying out a Table with javascript

Tags: javascript

I Need to make a table with javascript only (no html table tages or any frameworks).
The code in "Eloquent javascript: CH 6" . this is the code

```
  name         height country
 ------------ ------ -------------
 Kilimanjaro    5895 Tanzania
 Everest        8848 Nepal
 Mount Fuji     3776 Japan
 Mont Blanc     4808 Italy/France
 Vaalserberg     323 Netherlands
 Denali         6168 United States
 Popocatepetl   5465 Mexico
```

> Only Javascript codes

```
function rowHeights(rows) {
    return rows.map(function (row) {
        return row.reduce(function (max, cell) {
            return Math.max(max, cell.minHeight());
        }, 0);
    });
}

function colWidths(rows) {
    return rows[0].map(function (_, i) {
        return rows.reduce(function (max, row) {
            return Math.max(max, row[i].minWidth());
        }, 0);
    });
}
function drawTable(rows) {
    var heights = rowHeights(rows);
    var widths = colWidths(rows);

    function drawLine(blocks, lineNo) {
        return blocks.map(function (block) {
            return block[lineNo];
        }).join(" ");
    }

    function drawRow(row, rowNum) {
        var blocks = row.map(function (cell, colNum) {
            return cell.draw(widths[colNum], heights[rowNum]);
        });
        return blocks[0].map(function (_, lineNo) {
            return drawLine(blocks, lineNo);
        }).join("\n");
    }

    return rows.map(drawRow).join("\n");
}
```

> The rest of the code in the book

I wanna to understand how it works.as it confused me

Answer (score 1):

I have provided commented explanation to the functions you have mentioned in the question (courtesy of Gordon Zhu):

```
// Returns an array of row heights, one for each row.
    function rowHeights(rows) {
      // Transform each row.
      return rows.map(function(row) {
        // Reduce row to a single number,
        // the height of the tallest cell.
        return row.reduce(function(max, cell) {
          // Return max or the height of the current cell, 
          // whichever is larger.
          return Math.max(max, cell.minHeight());
        }, 0);
      });
    }

    // Returns array of minimum column widths,
    // one for each column.
    function colWidths(rows) {
      // Transform each column by looking at each 
      // cell in the first row of the table.
      // An underscore means the argument will not be used.
      return rows[0].map(function(_, i) {
        // Reduce each column to a single number,
        // the width of the widest column. Do this
        // by returning max or the width
        // of cell row[i], whichever is larger.
        // By looking at row[i] in every row, 
        // you will be able to look at every cell
        // in column i.
        return rows.reduce(function(max, row) {
          return Math.max(max, row[i].minWidth());
        }, 0);
      });
    }
    // Given an array of rows, draws a table.
function drawTable(rows) {
  // Get an array of heights for each row.
  var heights = rowHeights(rows);
  // Get an array of widths for each column.
  var widths = colWidths(rows);

  function drawLine(blocks, lineNo) {
    // Get a particular line across all blocks in a row,
    // joined by " ".
    return blocks.map(function(block) {
      return block[lineNo];
    }).join(" ");
  }

  // Function for drawing a single row.
  function drawRow(row, rowNum) {
    // Turn a single row into blocks. 
    var blocks = row.map(function(cell, colNum) {
      return cell.draw(widths[colNum], heights[rowNum]);
    });
    // For each line of content in a block, 
    // return a string that goes across all blocks.
    return blocks[0].map(function(_, lineNo) {
      return drawLine(blocks, lineNo);
    // Take each line of content, 
    // and join them into a single string
    // separated by newlines. This is a full row.
    }).join("\n");
  }

  // Draw each row and join with newlines.
  return rows.map(drawRow).join("\n");
}
```

Additionally, checkout [this](http://tomi.io/eloquent-javascript-laying-out-a-table/) and [this](https://jsgenie.blogspot.com/2015/07/laying-out-table-eloquent-javascript.html)
subsequently, you can try [Python Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/) to see what each line in any program does.

Comment: @MichaelGaskill while i understand that, you have to take into account that the question is asking for an explanation for a non trivial program with one function calling two or three functions inside them. Moreover, i don't expect participation from the questioner himself. Although to preserve the sanctity of SO, i have provided an explanation only to the code the questioner cared to mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The drawTable is the final function that makes this Laying out a Table but before making this table we need to run our data through some modification. drawTable function receives a grid of cell and dataTable function do the job.

Let's make out data short -

```
//data
var MOUNTAINS = [
  {name: "Everest", height: 8848},
  {name: "vaalserberg", height: 323}
]

// DrawTable Function will make our data a grid of cell
function dataTable(data) {
 var keys = Object.keys(data[0]);
 var headers = keys.map(function(name){
  return new UnderlinedCell(new TextCell(name));
 });
 var body = data.map(function(row){
  return keys.map(function(name){
   return new TextCell(String(row[name]));
  });
 });
 return [headers].concat(body);
}
console.log(drawTable(dataTable(MOUNTAINS)));


// Finally, our dataTable function will return -            
[[{inner: {text: ["name"]}}, {inner: {text: ["height"]}}], [{text: ["Everest"]},{text: ["5895"]}], [{text: ["Vaalserberg"]},{text: ["323"]}]]
```

rowHeights and colWidths function will determine what would be the maximum row height and maximum column width going to be for the table.

```
    function rowHeights(rows) {
        return rows.map(function (row) {
            return row.reduce(function (max, cell) {
                return Math.max(max, cell.minHeight());
            }, 0);
        });
    }

// For our data rowHeights will return - [2,1,1]

    function colWidths(rows) {
        return rows[0].map(function (_, i) {
            return rows.reduce(function (max, row) {
                return Math.max(max, row[i].minWidth());
            }, 0);
        });
    }

// For out data colWidths will return - [11,6]
```

Inside drawTable, function drawRow will use widths, heights and row data to make Laying out table.

This problem is really complex for the beginner. If you want explanation for every piece of code then check out this article - https://codient.blogspot.com/2015/11/laying-out-table-eloquent-javascript.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider the source code at the site of the book: http://eloquentjavascript.net/code/#6

Comment: I know the code but there's some parts that i can't understand

Comment: and what exactly do you not understand?

Comment: at first i didn't understand what dose this's code do
function Text(text){
     this.text = text.split("\n")
}
what's the usage of split